# Replace hive table with partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

There is a Hive-table with 2 string columns one partition "cmd_out".

I'm trying to rename all 2 columns ('col1', 'col2'), by using Replace-function:

```
Alter table 'table_test' replace columns(
  'col22' String,
  'coll33' String
)
```

But I receive the following exception:

```
 Partition column name 'cmd_out' conflicts with table columns.
```

When I include the partition column in query

```
Alter table 'table_test' replace columns(
  'cmd_out' String,
  'col22' String,
  'coll33' String
)
```

I receive:

```
Duplicate column name cmd_out in the table definition
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to rename a column, you need to use `alter table ... change`.
Here is the syntax

```
alter table mytab change col1 new_col1 string;
```